# CLLocation returns different values for CLLocationSpeed for different iPhone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, cllocationmanager

I am developing a trip based app. During testing on different devices I found that for same trip I am not getting same speed. 
I am using iPhone 6 and iPhone 7+ where I am calculating maximum speed on the data received speed from CLLocation. Both are totally different.

I am getting speed by

```
let speed: CLLocationSpeed = location.speed
```

This is different for both devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1) Use CLLocationManagerDelegate Delegate
Step 2) Write It's Delegate Method

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    [self speedCalculator:locations];
}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"%@",error.userInfo);
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

        NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

        if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied" message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:nil];

            [alertController addAction:ok];

            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}




-(void)speedCalculator:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
    double speeds = loc.speed;
    if (speeds > 0)
    {
        self.speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",speeds*3.6];
        SpeedValue = (float) (speeds*3.6) ;
    }
    else
    {
        self.speedLabel.text = @"0.00"; // When Device is not moving the Speed Value will become -ve.
        SpeedValue = 0.00 ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should I provide you code in Swift 3? Or you have checked this code in different devices and still it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

**CLLocationManager** class provide a different field of a location like Latitude, Longitude,accuracy and speed.

I used **CoreLocationController** so for location update i call this bellow method you can get current speed in **- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location** method like bellow

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
     NSString *currentSpeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [location speed]];
}
```

or otherwise bellow is delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"in update to location");
    NSString *currentSpeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [newLocation speed]];
}
```

You can also check [this tutorial](http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/) for more information.